# How to detect and pick-up changes in underlying schema for sql-server tvf functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have an inline-tvf function (assume name: cfn_test) that was defined like:

SELECT * FROM TableA;

Now, at the time of creation, the structure of TableA was:

colA, colB (the datatype doesn't matter at this point)

Let's add some data as well:

```
| colA | colB |
|   1  |  2   |
```

The application uses "SELECT * FROM cfn_test()", and gets:

```
| colA | colB |
|   1  |  2   |
```

Now the issue:

The structure of tableA changed, and a colC was inserted between colA and colB.Data:

```
| colA | colC | colB |
|   1  |   3  |   2  |
```

The application now gets:

```
| colA | colB |
|   1  |  3   |
```

If I run the SSMS-generated alter function script, without any changes, it now returns the correct results.

My question:
a) Is it possible to somehow detect which functions need to be "updated" based on the existence of "select *" in their text (i assume that's the culprit of the erroneous behaviour)

b) If I design a script that loops through all existing functions (using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[ROUTINES] ), can I somehow automatically generate the "alter function" script that SSMS generates and run it, so that all functions are updated with the current underlying schema?

Comment: It might help you to know that you do not need to alter function - you can run SP http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx to refresh it - `EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'cfn_test'`

Comment: Thank you, that's indeed very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)**  You can use system views - `sys.sql_modules` or `sys.sql_dependencies`

In `sql_modules` you can search for definition of your objects (functions, procedures, views) and find the pattern you need. Maybe something like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%TableA%' AND definition LIKE '%SELECT *%'
```

`sys.sql_dependencies` shows dependencies between object. So you can easily find all objects dependent on you TableA, after you change it. Might get you a bit results more than you need.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_dependencies 
WHERE referenced_major_id = object_id('TableA')
```

Either way, you can join it on `sys.objects` to get the names and filter for functions only (I would include views because they also need refreshing after underlaying object has changed)'. Something like this:

```
SELECT o.name FROM sys.sql_dependencies d
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON d.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE referenced_major_id = object_id('TableA')
AND o.type in ('FN', 'IF', 'TF', 'FS', 'FT', 'V')
```

**B)** After you found your function names, and after learning about [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) procedure for refreshing your dependent objects, it should not be that hard to generate script.

Simplest possible way is just generate EXEC for each, and copy/paste the result and run it:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' +  o.name + '''' FROM sys.sql_dependencies d
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON d.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE referenced_major_id = object_id('TableA')
AND o.type in ('FN', 'IF', 'TF', 'FS', 'FT', 'V')
```

If you want more automated, loop, concatenate single script and run it. I hope you can handle it.